# Spark structured streaming and filters

Tags: spark-streaming

Spark 2.1, structured streaming with primitive count(*), sum(field) is working ok on top of parquet files, but filtering is not working.
Sample code:

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.0.2.6.0.3-8
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_131)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val userSchema = new StructType()
  .add("caseId", StringType)
  .add("ts", LongType)
  .add("rowtype", StringType)
  .add("rowordernumber", IntegerType)
  .add("parentrowordernumber", IntegerType)
  .add("fieldname", StringType)
  .add("valuestr", StringType)

val csvDF = spark.readStream.schema(userSchema).parquet("/folder1/folder2")

csvDF.createOrReplaceTempView("tmptable")
val aggDF = spark.sql("select count(*) from tmptable where rowtype='3600'")

aggDF
  .writeStream
  .outputMode("complete")
  .format("console")
  .start()

aggDF
.writeStream
.queryName("aggregates")    // this query name will be the table name
.outputMode("complete")
  .format("memory")
  .start()
spark.sql("select * from aggregates").show()


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

+--------+
|count(1)|
+--------+
+--------+

import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
userSchema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(caseId,StringType,true), StructField(ts,LongType,true), StructField(rowtype,StringType,true), StructField(rowordernumber,IntegerType,true), StructField(parentrowordernumber,IntegerType,true), StructField(fieldname,StringType,true), StructField(valuestr,StringType,true))
csvDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [caseId: string, ts: bigint ... 5 more fields]
aggDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [count(1): bigint]

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
+--------+
|count(1)|
+--------+
|       0|
+--------+
```

Also I've tried noSQL style filtering:
val aggDF = csvDF.filter("rowtype == '3600'").agg(count("caseId"))

no success, and I've checked the parquet files, there are some rows where rowtype='3600'

```
[root@sandbox ~]# spark-sql
SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION is set to 2, using Spark2
spark-sql> select count(*) from tab1 where rowtype='3600' ;
433698463
```

Comment: Could you check what data do you have coming? Say, using this query: `select rowtype, count(*) from tmptable group by rowtype`.

Comment: Thanks for your hint ! rowtype, count(*) returned nulls for rowtype, I've checked avro-parquet file once again and found that in avro-parquet column name is rowType, not rowtype. This caused nulls in rowtype column.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not required to specify your own schema when your data is static. In this case Spark can figure out the schema of your parquet dataset on its own. E.g.:

```scala
case class Foo(lowercase: String, upperCase: String)
val df = spark.createDataset(List(Foo("abc","DEF"), Foo("ghi","JKL")))
df.write.parquet("/tmp/parquet-test")
val rdf = spark.read.parquet("/tmp/parquet-test")
rdf.printSchema
// root
//  |-- lowercase: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- upperCase: string (nullable = true)
```

At this stage, subsequent SQL queries would work disregards for the case:

```scala
rdf.createOrReplaceTempView("rdf")
spark.sql("select uppercase from rdf").collect
// Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([DEF], [JKL])
```

Spark has an option `spark.sql.caseSensitive` to enable/disable case sensitivity (default value is `true`) but it seems it only works on write.

An attempt to do the same with the stream will lead to an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Schema must be specified when creating a streaming
  source DataFrame. If some files already exist in the directory, then depending
  on the file format you may be able to create a static DataFrame on that directory
  with 'spark.read.load(directory)' and infer schema from it.
```

This leaves you with following options:

1. Provide your own schema as you did (be aware though that it is case sensitive).
2. Follow the advice in the exception and derive the schema from the data already stored in the folder:

```scala
val userSchema = spark.read.parquet("/tmp/parquet-test").schema
val streamDf = spark.readStream.schema(userSchema).parquet("/tmp/parquet-test")
```

3. Tell Spark to infer the schema anyway by setting `spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference` to `true`:

```scala
spark.sql("set spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference=true")
val streamDf = spark.readStream.parquet("/tmp/parquet-test")
streamDf.createOrReplaceTempView("stream_rdf")
val query = spark.sql("select uppercase, count(*) from rdf group by uppercase")
  .writeStream
  .format("console")
  .outputMode("complete")
  .start
```

Comment: I've got an exception on streaming dataframe:

 val csvDF = spark.readStream.parquet("/folder1/folder2")

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Schema must be specified when creating a streaming source DataFrame. If some files already exist in the directory, then depending on the file format you may be able to create a static DataFrame on that directory with 'spark.read.load(directory)' and infer schema from it.

Comment: Sorry, didn't test it on the stream, there is an option to enable schema inference on the stream. I've edited my answer to explain that.

Comment: Thanks, second option working OK. Maybe you can answer on next question: is it possible to pass files mask in readStream.parquet() ? Our ETL process sometimes merge small parquets into bigger one, because small files on hdfs is not efficient. But removed files cause error in streaming process (ERROR StreamExecution: Query terminated with error java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist) . Maybe it is possible to read new files only ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in rowtype column name, real column name in avro-parquet was "rowType". fix

```
.add("rowType", StringType)
```

solved the issue.